# How to generate engraving effect in CSS?

Tags: css

**Click** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR35z.png)

In the image, text just like carved in stone directly, how to generate this effect in CSS?

Comment: Try to experiment with text-shadow, that's the first thing that came to my mind http://www.css3generator.in/text-shadow.html

Comment: What have you tried? How far did you get and where are you stuck? I mean, which of the Google search results have you looked at? Google has far more answers than you will get here, and moreover, its answers are already there; you won't have to wait until someone types one in!

Comment: I have search a lot before, and also know text-shadow, text-shadow just add shadow for text. I really need is keeping text's outline and shadow, and remove text's background color, just like image show.

Answer (score 5):

Try to experiment with **text-shadow** property
Tips :

1. Background should be **pale** and text color should be **deep**
2. Text shadow to be **bright color**. Use more than one side of text effects.

HTML:

```
 <span>This is Engraved Effect</span>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #5D8D89;  
}

span { 
    color: #3B5957;
    font-size:72px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

Check link for reference
https://jsfiddle.net/pratikhegde/vkhej5au/

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this isn't what I need. The text background should be transparent, just like the image show, I need to see stone's color through text